# Openface: Ошибки во время тренировки

Tags: python, docker, lua, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Все действия проделываю в докере под Win 10.
Успешно порезал фотки для будущего обучения и выполняю вот такую команду из их хелпа http://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/demo-3-classifier/

```
./batch-represent/main.lua -outDir ./generated-embeddings/ -data ./aligned-images/
```

Но получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
{
  data : "./aligned-images/"
  imgDim : 96
  model : "/root/openface/models/openface/nn4.small2.v1.t7"
  device : 1
  outDir : "./generated-embeddings2/"
  cache : false
  cuda : false
  batchSize : 50
}
./aligned-images/
cache lotation:         /root/openface/aligned-images/cache.t7
Creating metadata for cache.
{
  sampleSize :
    {
      1 : 3
      2 : 96
      3 : 96
    }
  split : 0
  verbose : true
  paths :
    {
      1 : "./aligned-images/"
    }
  samplingMode : "balanced"
  loadSize :
    {
      1 : 3
      2 : 96
      3 : 96
    }
}

running "find" on each class directory, and concatenate all those filenames into a single file containing all image paths for a given class
now combine all the files to a single large file
load the large concatenated list of sample paths to self.imagePath
/root/torch/install/bin/luajit: /root/openface/batch-represent/dataset.lua:193: Could not find any image file in the given input paths
stack traceback:

        [C]: in function 'assert'
        /root/openface/batch-represent/dataset.lua:193: in function '__init'
        /root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:91: in function </root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:87>
        [C]: in function 'dataLoader'
        /root/openface/batch-represent/batch-represent.lua:19: in function 'batchRepresent'
        ./batch-represent/main.lua:42: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'dofile'
        /root/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:145: in main chunk
        [C]: at 0x00406670
```

Блок "Minimal Working Example to Extract Features" успешно выполняется без ошибок.

Подскажите как это пофиксить?

Comment: у вас изображения внутри контейнера доступны?

Comment: думаю что доступны, по команде ls я их вижу. Или вы имеливвиду права доступа?